# Change time zone?

Tags: support

Is there a settings/preference tab for changing the time zone? I looked all around my profile and searched the meta...

Thanks!

Comment: The site runs on UTC, regardless of where *you* are...

Comment: As in UTC + 0 ?

Comment: So far as I can tell, yes.

Comment: At the bottom of the new popup menue (triangle left to your user name) it shows the current time in UTC. I find this quite helpful.

Comment: In the top right corner of my MAC, it shows the current *local* time!

Comment: @TheChaz: But stackexchange runs on UTC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, all times are in UTC with the exception of chat.

Comment: So glad to finally have closure on this!